# Ruby on Rails RubyMine debugger issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I try to set up Rails Application in ruby 2.1.3 with RubyMine, however when it tries to install debugger it fails. I've tried a lot of different options, however haven't find any good solution. Pry debugger would work for ruby 2.1.3, however as far as I know pry debugger is not supported in RubyMine.

Could somebody advice good solution for debugging ruby 2.1.2 or ruby 2.1.3 at RubyMine? For now it works only with ruby 1.9.3, however I really want to use 2.1.3, but without debugger it's pointless.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: There is apparently some discussion on [some workarounds at this website](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9302), however given what's said in that conversation, it seems even now pry is still not integrated with rubymine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove pry debugger from your gemfile. thats what i did to make it work